# jQuery trigger event when click outside the element

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
$(document).click(function(evt) {
    var target = evt.currentTarget;
    var inside = $(".menuWraper");
    if (target != inside) {
        alert("bleep");
    }

});
```

I am trying to figure out how to make it so that if a user clicks outside of a certain div (menuWraper), it triggers an event.. I realized I can just make every click fire an event, then check if the clicked currentTarget is same as the object selected from $(".menuWraper"). However, this doesn't work, currentTarget is HTML object(?) and $(".menuWraper") is Object object? I am very confused.

Answer (score 77, accepted):

Just have your `menuWraper` element call `event.stopPropagation()` so that its click event doesn't bubble up to the `document`.

**Try it out:** http://jsfiddle.net/Py7Mu/

```
$(document).click(function() {
    alert('clicked outside');
});

$(".menuWraper").click(function(event) {
    alert('clicked inside');
    event.stopPropagation();
});
```

- http://api.jquery.com/event.stopPropagation/

Alternatively, you could `return false;` instead of using `event.stopPropagation();`

Answer (score 25):

if you have child elements like dropdown menus

```
$('html').click(function(e) {
  //if clicked element is not your element and parents aren't your div
  if (e.target.id != 'your-div-id' && $(e.target).parents('#your-div-id').length == 0) {
    //do stuff
  }
});
```

Comment: This is literally the best answer. Concise and understandable. Great.

Answer (score 12):

The most common application here is closing on clicking the document but not when it came from within that element, for this you want to stop the bubbling, like this:

```
$(".menuWrapper").click(function(e) {
  e.stopPropagation(); //stops click event from reaching document
});
$(document).click(function() {
  $(".menuWrapper").hide(); //click came from somewhere else
});
```

All were doing here is preventing the click from [bubbling up](http://www.quirksmode.org/js/events_order.html) (via [`event.stopPrpagation()`](http://api.jquery.com/event.stopPropagation/)) when it came from within a `.menuWrapper` element.  If this *didn't* happen, the click came from somewhere else, and will by default make it's way up to `document`, if it gets there, we hide those `.menuWrapper` elements.

Answer (score 4):

try these..

```
$(document).click(function(evt) {
    var target = evt.target.className;
    var inside = $(".menuWraper");
    //alert($(target).html());
    if ($.trim(target) != '') {
        if ($("." + target) != inside) {
            alert("bleep");
        }
    }
});
```

Answer (score 3):

```
$(document).click((e) => {
  if ($.contains($(".the-one-you-can-click-and-should-still-open").get(0), e.target)) {
  } else {
    this.onClose();
  }
});
```

Comment: I like this implementation

Answer (score 2):

I know that the question has been answered, but I hope my solution helps other people.

`stopPropagation` caused problems in my case, because I needed the `click` event for something else. Moreover, not every element should cause the div to be closed when clicked.

My solution:

```
$(document).click(function(e) {
    if (($(e.target).closest("#mydiv").attr("id") != "mydiv") &&
        $(e.target).closest("#div-exception").attr("id") != "div-exception") {
        alert("Clicked outside!");
    }
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/NLDu3/

Answer (score 1):

I do not think document fires the click event. Try using the body element to capture the click event. Might need to check on that...

Answer (score 1):

This code will open the menu in question, and will setup a click listener event. When triggered it will loop through the target id's parents until it finds the menu id. If it doesn't, it will hide the menu because the user has clicked outside the menu. I've tested it and it works.

```
function tog_alerts(){
   if($('#Element').css('display') == 'none'){
       $('#Element').show();
       setTimeout(function () {
           document.body.addEventListener('click', Close_Alerts, false);
       }, 500);
   }
}

function Close_Alerts(e){
   var current = e.target;
   var check = 0;
   while (current.parentNode){
      current = current.parentNode
      if(current.id == 'Element'){
         check = 1;
      }
   }
   if(check == 0){
      document.body.removeEventListener('click', Close_Alerts, false);
      $('#Element').hide();         
   }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
function handler(event) {
 var target = $(event.target);
 if (!target.is("div.menuWraper")) {
  alert("outside");
 }
}
$("#myPage").click(handler);
```

Answer (score 0):

try this one

```
    $(document).click(function(event) {

        if(event.target.id === 'xxx' )
            return false;
        else {
              // do some this here
        }

    });
```

Comment: Could you explain how/why this could be better than the already accepted answers?

Answer (score 0):

```
    var visibleNotification = false;

  function open_notification() {
        if (visibleNotification == false) {
            $('.notification-panel').css('visibility', 'visible');
            visibleNotification = true;
        } else {
            $('.notification-panel').css('visibility', 'hidden');
            visibleNotification = false;
        }
    }

    $(document).click(function (evt) {
        var target = evt.target.className;
        if(target!="fa fa-bell-o bell-notification")
        {
            var inside = $(".fa fa-bell-o bell-notification");
            if ($.trim(target) != '') {
                if ($("." + target) != inside) {
                    if (visibleNotification == true) {
                        $('.notification-panel').css('visibility', 'hidden');
                        visibleNotification = false;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    });
```