# Clicking the fade doesn't around lightbox doesn't close it

Tags: javascript, html, css

I want to create a button action where upon click, a video light box opens and when the visitor clicks anywhere else outside of the video (the fade), the video closes. So far, other features work except when I click on fade near the edge of the video, it doesn't close. So here's my html, css & js.

```
<div id="motionVideo">
            <div class='motionButton' onclick="motionLightbox_open();"></div>
           <div id="motionLight">
            <video id="motionShowreel" width='1280' height='720' controls>
              <source src="./motionGraphic.mp4" type="video/mp4">
                  <!--Browser does not support <video> tag -->
            </video>
          </div>
        
          <div id="motionFade" onClick="motionLightbox_close();">
          </div>
          
          <div class="motionShowreel">
            <video src="./motionGraphic.mp4" width="100%" height="50%"></video>
        </div>
        </div>
```

```
#motionVideo {
    /*background: #ffc8b2;*/
    grid-area: motionVideo;

}

.motionButton{
    background-image:url(./mg.png);
    background-position:center center;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: 70%;
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
    /*position: relative;
    top:20vh;
    left:-20vw;*/
}


.motionShowreel{
    width: 100%; 
    height: 100%; 
    position: relative;
    top: -120vh;
    left: 0vw;
    z-index: -1;
}

#motionFade {
    display: none;
    position: fixed;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    background-color: black;
    top:0%;
    left:0%;
    z-index: 1001;
    -moz-opacity: 0.8;
    opacity: .80;
    filter: alpha(opacity=80);
  }
  
  
  #motionLight {
    display: none;
    position: absolute;
    padding: 10vw;   
    top:0;
    align-items: center center;
    justify-content: center center;
    z-index: 1002;
    cursor: pointer;
  }
```

```
window.document.onkeydown = function(e) {
    if (!e) {
      e = event;
    }
    if (e.keyCode == 27) {
      motionLightbox_close();
    }
  }
  
  function motionLightbox_open() {
    var lightBoxVideo = document.getElementById("motionGraphic");
    window.scrollTo(0,150);
    document.getElementById('motionLight').style.display = 'block';
    document.getElementById('motionFade').style.display = 'block';
    lightBoxVideo.pause();
  }
  
  function motionLightbox_close() {
    var lightBoxVideo = document.getElementById("motionGraphic");
    document.getElementById('motionLight').style.display = 'none';
    document.getElementById('motionFade').style.display = 'none';
    lightBoxVideo.pause();
  }
```

When I try clicking on the fade near the edge of the video, the video doesn't close. Only by scrolling down further and clicking does it close. How do I fix this issue?

Comment: I tried to run your code it does not seem to generate any button?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [jQuery trigger event when click outside the element](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3314810/jquery-trigger-event-when-click-outside-the-element)

Comment: the button is the png file defined in the css for the <div class="motionButton">

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems like `div` by ID `motionLight` is occupying the space around the player (it has a huge padding). Try adding the close handler also to that `div`:

```
<div id="motionLight" onclick="motionLightbox_close()">
</div>
```

**Working example**

```js
window.document.onkeydown = function(e) {
  if (!e) {
    e = event;
  }
  if (e.keyCode == 27) {
    motionLightbox_close();
  }
}
  
function motionLightbox_open() {
  var lightBoxVideo = document.getElementById("motionGraphic");
  window.scrollTo(0,150);
  document.getElementById('motionLight').style.display = 'block';
  document.getElementById('motionFade').style.display = 'block';
  lightBoxVideo.pause();
}

function motionLightbox_close() {
  var lightBoxVideo = document.getElementById("motionGraphic");
  document.getElementById('motionLight').style.display = 'none';
  document.getElementById('motionFade').style.display = 'none';
  lightBoxVideo.pause();
}
```

```css
#motionVideo {
    /*background: #ffc8b2;*/
    grid-area: motionVideo;

}

.motionButton{
    background-color: #EEEEEE;
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
    width: 100px;
    height: 30px;
    /*position: relative;
    top:20vh;
    left:-20vw;*/
}


.motionShowreel{
    width: 100%; 
    height: 100%; 
    position: relative;
    top: -120vh;
    left: 0vw;
    z-index: -1;
}

#motionFade {
    display: none;
    position: fixed;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    background-color: black;
    top:0%;
    left:0%;
    z-index: 1001;
    -moz-opacity: 0.8;
    opacity: .80;
    filter: alpha(opacity=80);
  }
  
  
  #motionLight {
    display: none;
    position: absolute;
    padding: 10vw;   
    top:0;
    align-items: center center;
    justify-content: center center;
    z-index: 1002;
    cursor: pointer;
  }
```

```html
<div id="motionVideo">
  <div class="motionButton" onclick="motionLightbox_open();">Open</div>
  <div id="motionLight" onclick="motionLightbox_close()">
    <video id="motionShowreel" width='1280' height='720' controls>
      <source src="./motionGraphic.mp4" type="video/mp4">
        <!--Browser does not support <video> tag -->
    </video>
  </div>
        
  <div id="motionFade" onClick="motionLightbox_close();">
  </div>
          
  <div class="motionShowreel">
    <video id="motionGraphic" src="./motionGraphic.mp4" width="100%" height="50%"></video>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: changing the padding made the video bigger once clicked but did not solve the issue

Comment: Did you run the above snippet? I just added the event handler to the other `div`, and it works. Give it a try. Only changing the `padding` will not work here.